# Why HTTP/2 uses Pseudo-Header Fields?

Tags: http, http2

From the RFC7540:

> While HTTP/1.x used the message start-line (see [RFC7230], Section 3.1) to convey the target URI, the method of the request, and the status code for the response, HTTP/2 uses special pseudo-header fields beginning with ':' character (ASCII 0x3a) for this purpose.

So why HTTP/2 uses Pseudo-Header Fields? Is there anything wrong with the message start-line in HTTP/1.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lending an image from [Google's introduction to HTTP/2](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2#header_compression)

[image]

In this picture you can see that on the first request the first two header lines which are usually like:

```
GET /resoure HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.com
...
```

are now split up into a headers frame like this

```
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:host: example.com
:path: /resource
...
```

while the remaining headers are more or less the same, except for being all lower-case characters.

HTTP/2 tries to minimize the payload size as much as possible. It will also compress headers and strip headers that are equal to the headers sent in the previous request, as can be seen in the right part of the linked image.

In HTTP/1.1 a consecutive request looked like the first initial request just targeting a different resource:

```
GET /otherResource HTTP/1.1
Host: https://example.org
...
```

while in HTTP/2 a consecutive request to the same server just requires

```
:path: /otherResource
```

as all of the other headers are already available and can be restored from the previously cached and indexed headers.

This is therefore an optimization to reduce the payload on consecutive requests further.

Comment: So, by using  Pseudo-Header Fields,  we can reduce the headers  being sent? And for HTTP/1, it always had to send the request method and request protocol?

Comment: Yes, HTTP/1 and HTTP/1.1 require all of the headers to be sent on each request, as if it was the first request, while HTTP/2 supports stripping of headers on consecutive requests issued over the same multiplexed connection which allows to send only those headers that differ from the previous request. All the other headers are restored from the cached headers of the previous request.

Comment: The fact that omitting things on subsequent requests is possible is interesting, but doesn't answer why this information is encoded as headers and not as its own independent thing... Even if there were a separate 'status line' encoding, this wouldn't have precluded this optimization. but alas i guess it was a good enough answer for OP

Comment: @Evert Only the host pseudo-header would clash with its counterpart in HTTP/1.1. They could easily have gone for a different name in HTTP/2 though they decided to convert the first line into dedicated pseudo-headers, that do not clash with existing HTTP/1.1 headers. Maybe they have some advanced parsing techniques that speed up the extraction of `:key` within the Huffman compressed byte-stream or the just wanted to put more attention onto these changes. These are just speculations on my part. But they surely use it to reduce the payload size on consecutive requests

Comment: @RomanVottner that was one detail of my answer, but not the important part. If the information was encoded as a 'status line' type of thing, that optimization could still be made. The question was about, why are they encoded as headers. Optimization is not the core reason.

Comment: @Evert I think encoding status line as headers is to make all data in headers keep a key-value structure. And by doing that, they can all be benifit from the HPACK compression algorithm

Comment: @Chor, that's what I intended to convey with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 is new protocol, and with binary encoding.

There is no status line in HTTP/2, just like there are no 'lines' for individual headers. An entirely new way had to be invented to encode every part of a HTTP request.

Headers are effectively a key->value structure. Instead of inventing a different encoding for the things appearing on the first line of a HTTP/1.1 requests, it makes the protocol simpler if the same approach to encoding is used for this stuff.

After all, things like the 'path' and 'http method' are *already* in the header, why not take the same approach for encoding them as regular headers. The `:` in front ensures that there's no clashes with existing HTTP/1.1 headers, because the name of a header can never contain `:`.

So the tl;dr is: by encoding the information from the first line of HTTP requests and responses as special HTTP headers, the protocol could be simpler.